# How can i get Facebook back if the app won't re-download?

Tags: applications, iphone, facebook

[image: What comes up when I try to re-download]

iPhone Facebook app had a "bug fix" update so I clicked it and it wouldn't load. I deleted the app and reinstalled and now it keeps saying it can't be downloaded at this time. I've tried re-downloading it with both my Wi-Fi on and off and it still doesn't work!

Comment: Have you tried connecting your iPhone to iTunes, downloading the application to iTunes and then transferring the app across to the iPhone? I had this problem with an earlier version (5.x) and this is how I got around it and then it was suddenly fine again!

Comment: I dont have a computer/laptop to do that. Is there any other solution?

Comment: I know it'll sound silly but... have you tried turning it off and on again ? (oh and you can do a screenshot on your iphone by pressing the home and power buttons simultaneously ;))

Comment: I switched it on and off, still didn't work (last night) but all good it's up and running again now thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 2):

The servers of Apple did not allow downloading the Facebook application for some (unknown) reason. It was probably a bug.

Downloading Facebook on the iPhone now works again (at least in France).